# Yahoo Pipes .. remove nesting

Tags: xml, yahoo-pipes

Please forgive me if I am not explaing the question well as I don't know much about XML feeds.

In the image below, I want all the elements within guid elements to appear alongwith city, title, link attributes instead of being nested inside guid.

[image]

The reason is that the application I am inputting this xml feed can't find these elements. If there is another way of referencing to these elements when configuring them, please let me know e.g. should I just give imageurl or guid.imageurl for the script to be able to read these data items.

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The rename operator should do the job.